# Saving data into Database Using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

I have page which contains a form and when user submit form i want saving data into my database with using Ajax but i get error

> POST http://localhost:xxx/Account/ProcessRequestRMA 500 (Internal Server Error)

did i miss something ?! Can anyone please point me in right direction?!
thanks.

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(int? id ,string kundenavn, string ordrenummer)
{


    var SaveDb = db.RMA_History.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (SaveDb == null)
        db.RMA_History.Add(new RMA_History
        {   
            Kundenavn = kundenavn,
            Ordrenummer = ordrenummer,
        });

    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(SaveDb, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AJAX:

```
<form id="RMAForm">

<input name="Ordrenummer" id="Ordrenummer" type="text" >

<input name="Kundenavn" id="Kundenavn" type="text" >

//id
<input type="hidden" name="RMAID"  id="RMAID" />

<button id="btn" type="submit">Send</button>

</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function (e) {


            e.preventDefault();

            var kundenavn = $("#Kundenavn").val();
            var ordrenummer = $("#Ordrenummer").val();
            var id = $("#RMAID").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Account/ProcessRequestRMA",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {

                    kundenavn: kundenavn,
                    ordrenummer: ordrenummer,
                    id : id

                },

                success: function (status) {
                    if (status == null) {
                        status.Kundenavn = kundenavn;
                        status.Ordrenummer = ordrenummer;

                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Try Again");
                    }
                },

                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            });


        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Stick a breakpoint in the controller action and see what's happening there.

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means that the server is throwing  an exception. Debug you code to determine what it is (including using the browser tools - the Network tab - to inspect the response which will give you the details of the exception)

Comment: @BarryO'Kane : i did its tell me id is null

Comment: You are passing a Nullable<int> by passing int? ID, I guess you need to set your database to increment the ID or use a Queue on the database to generate a new ID for the id column

Comment: @ComputerAidedTradingSystems i did this beacuse i dont have any row in database and its give me error about Nullable and than i make id Nullable.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just Debug the code again , it tell me id=0 and its beacuse i give value in input field 0 , and when i remove value attr it tell me id is null , i think problem is some how i should catch id , and i dont how exactly

Comment: You have given it a `value="0"` so of course it will be `0` in the controller method - what are you expecting it to be, and why are you not binding to a model?

Comment: @StephenMuecke would please give me an example with my code or something!

Comment: I have no idea what your models are, or what you expect the value of `id` to be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke just minute , i will update my question

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just update my question view Model & ViewModel

Comment: Generate you view correctly by binding to your model and using the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods (e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)` etc. (and all you need is `data: $('form').serialize(),` in the ajax. And the POST method should also be `public JsonResult ProcessRequestRM(RMASAVE model)`

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke i will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
var kundenavn = $("#kundenummer").val();
var ordrenummer = $("#Ordrenummer").val();
```

?

I guess since the id is wrong the javascript is crashing at

```
$("#kundenavn ").val()
```

due to undefined element

Comment: sorry sorry my bad i just forget to change it , i just update my question

Comment: @7seconds If you go through Chrome or Firefox console what error do you get? Could you provide more details?

Comment: i get this > POST http://localhost:xxxx/Account/ProcessRequestRMA 500 (Internal Server Error) <br> something went wrong - debug it!

Comment: @7seconds Yeah but what in console? What if you click on the error in chrome console? It should give you more details

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to identify the part which is causing error. I think you are getting this error because of your db code. Please comment the db code and then run it. It should hopefully work. if it does then find out what is the error in db code by debugging. The db error could be because of many reasons, one of them could be the column ID in database is not nullable.

```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult ProcessRequestRMA(int? id ,string kundenavn, string ordrenummer)
   {


//var SaveDb = db.RMA_History.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

//if (SaveDb == null)
//    db.RMA_History.Add(new RMA_History
//    {   
//        Kundenavn = kundenavn,
//       Ordrenummer = ordrenummer,
//   });

// db.SaveChanges();

return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```